# How can I force a protocol to be linked in a library when no class in the library adopts it?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

It appears that if I declare an Objective-C protocol in a project but no classes in the project/target actually adopt the protocol, the runtime doesn't know about the protocol at runtime. (i.e. `NSProtocolFromString(@"MyProtocol")` returns `NULL`) However, if I add a minimal "dummy" class, like this:

```
@interface Dummy : NSObject < MyProtocol >
@end
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
@implementation Dummy
@end
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

...the runtime *will* know about the existence of the protocol at runtime.

Is there a more elegant/less-hacky way to ensure that an otherwise-unadopted protocol will be "known" at runtime?

Comment: This is probably related to some sort of linker optimization.

Comment: This is not a linker bug, but due to how protocols are actually implemented. A protocol is not a distinct instance, instead an instance of that protocol object is created for every class that implements it. Therefore, a protocol *cannot* exist without a class that implements it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `@protocol(MyProtocol)` instead of `NSProtocolFromString(@"MyProtocol")`. I found it near the bottom of this page http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/. Does that help answer the question?

Comment: I suppose it's fewer characters than the "dummy class" approach, but it's still code-polluting. I'm looking for a linker flag or something like that which doesn't require referencing the protocol in code.